# react native PushNotificationIOS doesn't listen push notification

Tags: push-notification, reactjs, react-native

I'm testing react-native PushNotificationIOS.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content

I bind event like below in `componentWillMount` function

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', this._onNotification);
```

and I send push notification from server to device. 
It doesn't catch push notification.

I only can received push notification below object c code

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
}
```

`PushNotificationIOS` can listen with `RCTDeviceEventEmitter` call.
but notification from server can't listen.

Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors? I wonder if this helps: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/565

Comment: I don't see any error. I did as http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries.html#content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Push notifications don't work out of the box and this is not documented on the React Native docs. There are a few things you need to add to your project first in order to wire up notifications. I found this information from an open issue on github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/1979#issue-94795697.

You basically need to wire the notifications manually in AppDelegate.m and call the corresponding methods from the RCTPushNotificationManager so the PushNotificationsIOS class can handle them from your javascript code.

1. add RCTPushNotification to your project (and also link binaries in build settings).
2. add this header to Header Search Paths: `$(SRCROOT)/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/**`
3. add this code to AppDelegate.m:

---

```
#import "RCTPushNotificationManager.h"

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [RCTPushNotificationManager application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [RCTPushNotificationManager application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
    [RCTPushNotificationManager application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: I'm following these steps but Xcode can't find `RCTPushNotificationManager.h` how can I fix it ?

Comment: @MelihMucuk If you added the `RCTPushNotification.xcoceproj` to your Libraries folder and added `$(SRCROOT)/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/**` header search path to your project target under Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths xcode should be able to find the header file. If xcode still can't find it you might try deleting the derived files for your project at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and rebuilding.

Comment: nothing changed. `#import "../../Libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotificationManager.h"` If I import like this, Xcode find required lib.

Answer (score 1):

I found this too so wrote a replacement module to handle receiving push notifications - https://github.com/darylrowland/react-native-remote-push

Comment: You should include the information form the link and add it as reference. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however your plugin seems to have errors with React Native 0.4.4 Daryl? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? installed via npm.

Comment: Would you please add some instruction on how to add your library to existing react-native project. and also npm install messes up with project so I have to clean node-modules and reinstall everytime I npm install the lib